# Implementing algorithms using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a webbased application using javascript and I am applying a lot of algorithms on my data and a lot of processing on data is required.
I was wondering is it the common practice to do all the processing and implementing algorithms using javascript or should I do them somewhere else ( i.e. server side ) and just give the results to javascript for viewing?

Comment: I like to do any processing server side.  You have to keep in mind that some people are using IE6 :-s IE7 :-s IE8 :-s.  Some are on slow computers and slow browsers.  If you want to manipulate the DOM thats one thing.  If you need complex `algorithms` stick it in the server.  Your server should have much more processing power than a browser...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what you're trying to do!

Generally if it's data crunching, you want to do that server side, and then present it to the user. Sometimes it can be helpful to offload some of this work to your client- but keep in mind, if you're pushing computing onto the client, it may cause a page to take longer to load.